# I need to convert the below CSV data to a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I need to convert this CSV data to an javascript array:

```
5/27/2019 19:54:09,5/27/2019, GSCOH6EUYN77D5N5HB22222222,"defgv",street
5/27/2019 20:21:58,5/27/2019, ZJ2ZOMAFNGTWEITTD333333333,"defgv",apartment
5/27/2019 20:33:09,5/27/2019, E3V5MNRGDU4WV4QVD444444444,"defgv",address
5/27/2019 20:34:39,5/27/2019, NQ5TZYVDIDBCEXBYC555555555,"defgv",home
```

I have tried to use :

```
var dataArr = xmlData.split("\n");
var data = dataArr.splice(1,dataArr.length-1);
```

but it doesn't work..think its because of the space in the character defgv.Could you please help me to convert this.

Expected output:-

```
["5/27/2019 9:54:09,5/27/2019,GSCOH6EUYN77D5N5HB22222222,defgv,street",
"5/27/2019 20:21:58,5/27/2019,OMAFNGTWEITTD333333333,defgv,apartment"]
```

Instead m receiving the output as :

```
0: "5/22/2019 17:10:08,5/22/2019, GSCOH6EUYN77D5N5HB22222222,""
1: "      defgv",street
"
2: "5/22/2019 17:24:19,5/22/2019, OMAFNGTWEITTD333333333,""
3: "      defgv",apartment
"
```

Comment: Actually the data contains "/n   defgv",street /n in between the lines so m not sure how to convert this to an array as expected above.Please do help me to find an solution for this.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the actual input format?

Comment: You could replace "/n defgv" by "defgv" before the split? Or use regular expressions...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what your input format is.  But taking a guess at it, you might have to split into strings and then combine pairs of them into single strings.  This would do that:

```js
const splitIntoJointRows = (data) =>   data .split ('\n')
       .reduce ((a, s, i, ss) => i % 2 ? [...a, ss[i - 1] + s] : a, [])

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------

const data = `5/27/2019 19:54:09,5/27/2019, GSCOH6EUYN77D5N5HB22222222,
     "defgv",street
5/27/2019 20:21:58,5/27/2019, ZJ2ZOMAFNGTWEITTD333333333,
     "defgv",apartment
5/27/2019 20:33:09,5/27/2019, E3V5MNRGDU4WV4QVD444444444,
     "defgv",address
5/27/2019 20:34:39,5/27/2019, NQ5TZYVDIDBCEXBYC555555555,
     "defgv",home
`;

console .log (
  splitIntoJointRows(data)
)

console .log (
  splitIntoJointRows(data)
    .map(s => s.split(/,\s*/))
)

console .log (
  splitIntoJointRows(data)
    .map(s => s.split(/,\s*/))
    .map(([date, a, b, c, d]) => ({date, a, b, c, d}))
)
```

Also in that snippet is a call that use this to build an array of arrays of fields and one that further converts this to an array of objects (with invented keys.)

Comment: Cool.Thankyou Scott.Idealyy i need the final output to be like:["E3V5MNRGDU4WV4QVD444444444":"5/27/2019 19:54:09,5/27/2019,defgv,street",
 "OMAFNGTWEITTD333333333":"5/27/2019 19:54:09,5/27/2019,defgv,home"]having OMAFNGTWEITTD333333333 as a key and remainign to be a value.

Comment: Also when i tried using your above code,

 m getting result as 0: "      defgv",home
5/22/2019 17:10:08,5/22/2019, GSCOH6EUYN77D5N5HB22222222,""
1: "      defgv",street
5/22/2019 17:24:19,5/22/2019, OMAFNGTWEITTD333333333,""
2: "      defgv",Apartment
5/22/2019 17:26:08,5/22/2019, NS7NDU5M2WCXBW5XATOPNWRW3U,"" which i feel is not as expected.Could you please help me to fix this.

Comment: @arr: You need to put some work into this question.  Please edit it to include a snippet that shows the actual current output and a formatted version of the expected output.  (Your comment here and the question seem to detail entirely different formats, and the one here is not valid JS syntax.)

Comment: @arr: I look forward to it. Please note that I mis-typed above.  We do need the expected output of course, but what's really missing is an accurate version of the expected **input**.